# MySQL returned an empty result set when i just build the table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I just build a table "id" using phpmyadmin. The structure part shows what I build,
however the browse part returned an empty result set. And the rows of table "id" are zero.
Why is that? I've already built it! I am new to mysql, forgive me.
[image: browse part]
[image: structure part]
[image: row is zero]

Comment: Have you only built it? or have you also populated it with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you read a guide before continuing.

As for your issue, assuming you'd like to save the ID, NAME and the SCORE of a player in a game, you would do it as follows:

Create a table called "Players" and 3 fields named "ID", "NAME" and "SCORE". Then create a file in PHP with the following content:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Players (ID, NAME, SCORE)
    VALUES ('0', 'Michael',35)");

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Players (ID, NAME, SCORE)
    VALUES ('1', 'Joe',33)");

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Replace the "HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD" and "DATABASE_NAME" with yours.

What you currently did was create a table called "ID" and 3 fields named "111", "222" and "333". That is not the correct way to use a database.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The browse tab makes you browse whatever data or rows you have enterned inside the table. since the table is new and just created, to my best guess you didn't insert any values in it yet, you can do that with the insert tab with the following syntax.

> INSERT INTO Table_Name (Field_name) VALUES (Field_Value)